# How to use Advanced Python Scheduler aka apscheduler with if conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, scheduler, apscheduler

Below code runs for if condition only, and doesn't switch to elif condition.
'''
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()
activetrade = None
def main():
    global activetrade
    if activetrade == None:
        print("Inside main function and activetrade is ", activetrade, datetime.now())
        pass
    activetrade1 = 1
    activetrade = activetrade1
    print("This is active trade variable after changing value ", activetrade, datetime.now())

def take_trade():
    global activetrade
    print("Inside taketrade function.")
    print("Inside taketrade function, activetrade variable is ", activetrade)
    activetrade2 = 0
    activetrade = activetrade2
    print("Active trade global variable after assigning value is ", activetrade)

if activetrade == None:
    sched.add_job(main, 'interval', seconds=5)
    pass
    sched.start()

elif activetrade == 1:
    sched.add_job(take_trade, 'interval', seconds=1)
    sched.start()
```

'''

Comment: At the time when the condition is evaluated, the value is always `None`. Why do you expect the module code to be run more than once?

Comment: Thanks @AlexGrönholm for replying.
I made some changes to code which are as follows:
1. set activetrade before main function as 0.
2. Called main() function before if condition.

After doing this, the condition switches to elif condition, however in elif condition I am changing the active trade variable to 0, which must go back to if condition which is not working, it simply keeps running elif condition.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding of how Python code is being run. Your code is being run on the module level first, and contrary to what you're claiming, your code does NOT run the main() function before the "if" block, but only after selecting the first branch (`activetrade == None`). Then the execution is blocked at `sched.start()`. Did you think the interpreter would somehow run _both_ "if" branches if you changed the value of the `activetrade` variable _after_ one of the blocks was selected?

Comment: Yes, I thought that way, however now it is clear that once it goes in if loop it keeps running since it is scheduled and even if activetrade variable is changed it doesn't go back to elif condition.


Is there any other module or any other way to achieve this task?

i.e., running second function based on the results of main function and having time duration/frequency of both functions being different time interval.

Comment: I could probably give you a complete answer if you could edit the question to contain a comprehensive explanation of what you want to accomplish here.